# how to clear current contents of input buffer but NOT ignore the next few inputs

Tags: c++, loops, buffer, getch

Im making a typing game for fun. It will show a random word on screen, and you have to type it out.
Im using getch() in a loop. 
Each iteration it checks the letter entered and as soon as you make a mistake it will deduct points, play a sound effect sound effect and move on to next word.

I'm trying to make it ignore inputs entered during the time the sound effect is playing. 
Naturally, it takes some time to realise I made a mistake, so if I dont add this, I end up making multiple mistakes as the next few words flash by while im still typing the old word. (I think other people would have the same problem, or maybe its just me? :p )

Ive tried placing
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits::max(), '\n')
before the input loop but they screw something up and getch() stops work. you can type normally, as its no longer snatched up by getch(). I also have to press enter twice to move on. I need to clear only whats in the buffer and nothing further
Ive tried other stuff, but they all give similar results.

Is there any way to do what Im planning?

```
while (1){              

    randword = "youtube";
    cout << endl << endl << "The word is " << randword;
    cout << endl << "<< ";


    //some code here to clear ONLY whats IN the buffer (so it doesnt eat the next few inputs and etc)
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

        int poscounter = 0;                                                                     // counts how many letters typed so far, and if all typed then of course gives total number of letter in word
        for (std::string::iterator it = randword.begin(); it != randword.end(); ++it){          // allows input loop to cycle thru letters of the word until the end. but doesnt count them, so have to manually do that with poscounter
            poscounter = poscounter + 1;


            randwordcurrent = *it;                                                              // get letter of word at current iterator position


            playertempanswer = _getch();                                                        // get player answer. no need for enter! however _getch() does not display the input, so must output manually.
                cout << playertempanswer;                                                           // manual output since getch() does not display user input


                            if (playertempanswer == randwordcurrent){                                   // correct answer

                            PlaySound(TEXT("rightfx.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);

                            playeranswerstate = 1;

                            }


                            else if ((playertempanswer != randwordcurrent) && (playertempanswer != "|")){                           // incorrect answer, but not exit game trigger either

                            playeranswerstate = 0;

                            break;                                                                                      // break out of for loop early
                            }



        } // end of randword input loop








        if (playeranswerstate == 1){                                                                                    // actions for right answer
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(milliseconds(160));                                                             // give time for rightfx to finish before playing the wordrightfx
            PlaySound(TEXT("wordrightfx.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
        }

        else if (playeranswerstate == 0){                                                                               // actions for wrong answer
            PlaySound(TEXT("wrongfx.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(milliseconds(500));                                                             // give time for wrongfx to finish ()
        }



} //end of infinite while loop
```

stripped down version of the project showing only the necessary parts:
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=EE70CC84F483296F!1864&authkey=!ABLuRHvr_SNlaKs&ithint=folder%2c

Comment: Don't try to remove them, read them in and process in your logic. Also you should really learn how to format code properly.

Comment: Please reformat your code

Comment: what do you mean by "read them in and process"? How would I go about doing that? 
And yea i will try to improve my coding practices. The 1 semester introductory course didn't really teach much lol

Comment: You're trying to handle streams in a strange way, with this notion of "now". There is no notion of "now". Consider only sequences of characters arriving from the stream, not the time at which some of those characters were entered in any of the numerous buffers between the user and your program. Whenever dealing with stream input, ask yourself whether what you're trying to do would work with input piped from a file. If it wouldn't, you're doing streams wrong.

Comment: If you want a fully interactive application, this is not really the right tool for the job.

Comment: Oh I see about the streams now. Im a very noob coder so I dont know any other way. I just wanted to build a simple game in the console for fun lol. 

So is what  Bartek Banachewicz suggested a possible workaround? and how would I actually do it?